# Is there a name for a place where chains are made?

Tags: terminology, toponyms, business-language

I know that a factory that makes ropes is a *ropery*, but neither '*chainery*' nor '*chainworks*' seem to actually be real (or at least *popular*) terms for a place that produces chains.
I hunted around a bit and didn't come back with anything obvious, so I got to thinking that maybe it's something I wouldn't guess (a place that makes or deals in candles, for instance, is a '*chandler*').

Does anyone know a term for a place that makes chains?
I'm referring more to heavy, industrial-type chains that you might find in a factory or on a ship, rather than to jewellery-type chains (although if you know the name for a place which produces either or both types of chain, please go ahead and share it).

Comment: Almost certainly a *foundry*. In the past, chains would have been made by blacksmiths.

Comment: @Mick I was thinking of a 'forge' or 'metalworks', but I was angling towards something a bit more specific just to chains (as with ropes). Maybe there's no such particular term at all, but I won't know unless I ask. :D

Comment: [*Chain shops*](http://www.bclm.co.uk/locations/chain-making-shop/42.htm#.WDx4cFybvGg) (or *chain makers*), apparently.

Comment: I Googled around and could find nothing.  Heavy chains tended to come out of shipworks in the past, while lighter ones come wire manufacturers.  "Foundry" is only correct for chains that are cast, and that's a small (and vanishing) segment, from what I can gather.

Comment: @Mick And if Cradley Heathens and other Black Country folk couldn't come up with a better name than that, no-one could!

Comment: You'd almost think it would be a *catenary*.

Comment: @tchrist CatenEry surely, catenAry is an adjective. But so many if the old chainmakers were women I'll bet that most people didn't think they deserved a specific name for their place of work!

Comment: A chain store! -

Comment: How about _smithy_?

Comment: @anemone Smithy made monsters, not chains. :y Huehuehue. Anyway, yeah, to that, I was thinking of a more specific, documented, single term for a place that made chains in particular, rather than a more generic term for a metal shop. I could say _chainworks_ or _chainery_ and people would know what I mean, but neither actually seem to be "actual words."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sadly, no.**

There are very few private chain manufacturing specialist facilities, so no common term evolved. Chains are typically manufactured in much larger shops along with a variety of other products, generally only as they relate to one another in some end-product. Any terminology used by the staff of such a factory for "the place where we make chains", (such as "the chain shop", or "chainworks") would be shop slang. Unless/until such terminology became widespread across industry, or a selection of dedicated chain manufacturing subsidiaries began using common terminology for themselves, there is no one word for such a place. In general though, a production line for any given product will be called a "product"-mill, "product"-shop, or "product"-works, unless they refer to it by the material being consumed, or the process used. A modern chain shop could just as easily be called a steel mill or simply a "forge welder". If it's in the same building as other product lines, it might even just be called a "fabrication shop".

**Why?**

The main reason for this decentralization of chain manufacturing is that, while most chains are cosmetically identical, they are generally made with [very specific properties](http://blog.cmworks.com/understanding-the-difference-between-chain-grades-and-how-theyre-used/) to serve a specific intended function. Chains used for rigging of crane equipment are very different from those used as guarding, which are themselves different from those used as a mechanical drive, etc. You can't take a chain made for the guard rail on the side of a farm machine and use it to hoist something by a crane- they don't have the same properties. (Well, technically you *can*, it's just a bad idea.) As a result, chains are generally manufactured by the same people who make whatever it is meant for, even if they have subsidiaries or separate factories to carry out the process. Rigging chains are made by crane equipment manufacturers, towing chains are made by heavy equipment manufacturers, [tethering chains are made by boat manufacturers](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=k_LA_R4ifYk), decorative chains are made by jewellers, etc.

Even though early smithies and foundries did not have a contemporary theoretical understanding of the chemical and physical properties of Steel, they did understand basic metallurgy and how to *control* the physical properties of their products. Ancient blacksmiths would have been well aware of the fact that a chain made for one thing probably wouldn't be good at much of anything else aside from simply *being a chain*. Because [traditional chain smithing](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zRPos5uyy0A) was a [slow, difficult process](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NVgocBiNV6k) requiring [precision and skill](http://www.lostcrafts.com/Farm/Blacksmithing-7.html), they would have only been made in shops which had specific need for them, or dealt with customers who had regular need for them. That trend simply carries on to this day. Being a specialist "chain maker" doesn't make much sense if each of your products are only technically (and legally) valid for a very limited range of functions and you have to compete with your customer's own production team.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a ***chainworks***.

See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Lenox_%26_Co_Ltd

It's similar to steelworks and [ironworks](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ironworks).

> ironworks: a factory where iron is produced or iron objects are made

*(Cambridge Dictionary)*

Comment: Seems good but do you have some more substantial evidence of usage — more than just a Wikipedia link — perhaps try Google Ngrams.

Comment: I was thinking 'chainworks' too, but it didn't actually seem to formally be "a word" so much as an obvious term you'd [sic: "I'd"] expect, but one which nobody has properly taken up. :/

Comment: @Augusta - Although I haven't found it in a dictionary (I confess I didn't try more than 2 or 3), it was in common use in a place I lived once that used to have one.